# .htaccess file and subdirectories

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a domain with this filesystem:

> /root/public_html/subdirectory1/subdirectory2/

Inside the `subdirectory1` I have an `index.html` but the main point for my domain is

```
/subdirectory2/index.php (wordpress cms)
```

I want that if the user writes `www.dominio.com` it works like

```
www.dominio.com/subdirectory2/index.php
```

What are the .htaccess files that i have to insert in `/public_html/` and `/subdirectory1/`?

I did some tries but I can only have the following thing:

WWW.domain.com --> www.domain.com/subdirectory1/index.html (this works!)

1) .HTACCESS FILE in public_html

```
# Do not change this line. 
RewriteEngine on 
# Change example.com to be your main domain. 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?dominio.com$ 
# Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main domain. 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdirectory1/
# Don't change the following two lines. 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
# Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main domain. 
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdirectory1/$1 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?dominio.com$ 
 RewriteRule ^(/)?$ subdirectory1/index.html [L]
```

Comment: Show those tries as well.

Comment: Why do you need a directory two deep for wordpress? Can't you just create two folders inside public_html, sub1 and sub2 instead of sub2 being inside sub1. That seems like unnecessary complications. Also wordpress htaccess can act differently inside folders depending on your setup. https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess